# POJO for JSON array without keys [Long, Double]

Tags: java, android, gson, pojo

I have this JSON:

```
{
    "entries": [
        [
            1545230391429,        // long
            3799.9872120695404    // double
        ],
        [
            1545230685249,
            3796.6928339346546
        ],
        [
            1545231000586,
            3793.6487491594485
        ],
        ...
    ]
}
```

This POJO can handle them as Strings, but then I need to manually convert them to proper types... aaaand it's risky:

```
@SerializedName("entries")
@Expose
private List<List<String>> entries;
```

I tried with more robust way, but it's not working properly:

```
public class Entry {
    public Long timestamp;
    public Double value;
}

@SerializedName("entries")
@Expose
private List<Entry> entries;
```

I get

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 13 path
>   $.entries[0]

I think the problem is that `Entry` should be a `List`, but I can't make a list with two different types.

How to proceed?

Comment: can you change the json or is from an external source?

Comment: No, I can't change the JSON. @Hulk, "BEGIN_OBJECT expected but BEGIN_ARRAY found" error. `Entry` should be a List, but a List can only be of one type only.

Comment: @Vall0n, sure, it's valid (RFC 4627). I added the comments though.

Comment: yes, my bad. I missed the comma on the last inner array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MyData Class

```
@SerializedName("entries")
@Expose
private List<List<String>> entries;
```

Try with a custom deserialized (this is just a sample, check the code)

```
JsonDeserializer<MyData> deserializer = new JsonDeserializer<MyData>() {  
    @Override
    public MyData deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        List myList = new ArrayList<Entry>()

        JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("entries");

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
          Entry entry = new Entry(
                new Long(arr[0]),
                new Long(arr[1])
          );
          myList.add(entry)
        }



        return new MyData(myList);
    }
};
```

Comment: This seems to be the only option and is similar to what I was doing now. I'll accept.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to parse an two dimension array into a List. First you should parse it as an Object array of two dimension and iterate over it parsing it and filling a List.

Comment: Can you write down how `entries` should look like in POJO? I tried `private Entry[] entries;` but still got the same error.

Comment: Something like `private Object[][] entries;`

Comment: Maybe this helps too https://memorynotfound.com/gson-array-and-multi-dimensional-array/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with a pojo class (e.g. `EntryArrayHolder`) that holds the data of the first array.

```
public class Entry {
    public Long timestamp;
    public Double value;
}

public class EntryArrayHolder {
    private List<Entry> entriesHolder = null;
}

@SerializedName("entries")
@Expose
private List<EntryArrayHolder> entries= null;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: yes i also tested it just yet. I think you need an adapter [like below answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53871557/3559908)